# .htaccess 301 Redirect with HTTPS

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

I recently had a client site change a page name, for SEO purposes, and we needed to do a redirect on the old link to the new one, but for some reason its not working correctly.

The .htaccess looks like this:

```
AddHandler php5-script .php
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule    ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Redirect 301 /oldpage1  /newpage1
Redirect 301 /oldpage2  /newpage2
```

But the page gets redirected to be:

```
http://examplesite.com:443/newpage1
```

I've even tried doing the 301's like this:

```
Redirect 301 /oldpage1  https://examplesite.com/newpage1
```

Both ways produce the same result. Any ideas?

Comment: What gets redirected to `http://examplesite.com:443/newpage1`?

Comment: If I click a link from `https://examplesite.com/oldpage1`, it should go to `https://examplesite.com/newpage1`, but Instead goes to `http://examplesite.com:443/newpage1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not mix `mod_rewrite` rules with `mod_alias` ones and also you need to keep external redirect rules before internal rewrite ones.

Try this:

```
AddHandler php5-script .php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^oldpage1/?$ /newpage1 [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^oldpage2/?$ /newpage2 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try later tonight during off-peak hours and let you know how it works.